# The object is in a detached state. This operation cannot be performed on an ObjectStateEntry when the object is detached

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

There's a pile of MVC/EF code that I am debugging that someone else has transliaterated-from-Java written.

One snippet from the code resembles this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var context = new Models.FooEntities())
        {
            var exp = context.Expenses.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == 17);

            if (exp != null)
            {
                context.Expenses.DeleteObject(exp);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return Content("Deleted");
    }
```

Simple. Right? It should delete the entity Expense with the ID 17.

However, the call to `SaveChanges` raises an `InvalidOperationException` with the message, `"The object is in a detached state. This operation cannot be performed on an ObjectStateEntry when the object is detached."`

Now, I understand the message and I am surprised because the entity under question is never detached from the context. At least from what I see in the snippet above.

There could be more than meets the eye, but I'll consider that as an option when I have no more choices because it's a nightmare to track the entire call-stack of this vasts piece of transliteration of mostly badly written Java code that no one understands.

Comment: The only thing I can think of at first glance is that lazy loading is disabled in the context itself _and_ that deleting the entity triggers a cascaded delete that is mapped, but not implemented by a cascaded deleting FK constraint in the database.

Comment: That makes a whole lot of sense. Thank you. Amma try it tomorrow and report back.

Comment: It can also be a collection that's not lazy loading because it is not `virtual`, or proxy generation can be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making modification like this:

```
if (exp != null)
            {
                context.Expenses.Attach(ex);
                context.Expenses.DeleteObject(exp);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message and was also sure that the entity was not detached from the DbContext. In my case it turned out I forgot to define a complex type that resided in the class that was apparantly detached. At compile time and at database construction time nothing seemed to go wrong but at runtime this error occured. Once the complex type was properly mapped it went as expected. Perhaps something similar is the case in your situation (which is probably solved by now).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I had tried to update an entity such as member with a status using the code:

```
member.status = newStatus;
```

While in my entity mapping setup I had the following code:

```
HasRequired(t => t.Status).WithMany(t => t.EmployeeStatus).Map(m => m.MapKey("StatusId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I fixed the issue by assigning the Id to the entity as needed and did my save/update via a unit of work:

```
member.StatusId = newStatus.StatusId;
```

Not sure if this will help anyone, and not even sure why this occurred? but I got the error above, and the update assignment of the **ID** fixed the issue.